# How to use parallel programming to receive and transmit signal in matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, simultaneous, usrp

I’m working on a radar project using USRP N210 with UBX-40 daughterboard. It is taking time receive the transmitted echoes. I want to use parallel programming but i don't have any idea about it any help?!!

Comment: That is not how parallel programming works, *at all*. With parallel programming you can compute faster, but you can not increase communication speeds.

Comment: Let me put a more simple example for better understanding. You are asking: I need to go to London by car faster, its too slow. Should I buy 4 cars? No, more cars will not make you travel faster!

Comment: you can use parfor if you meant to compute the received data else if you are transmitting over a single transmitter see @AnderBiguri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [While loop is taking too much time to execute, also within the loop elapsed time is large](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49844527/while-loop-is-taking-too-much-time-to-execute-also-within-the-loop-elapsed-time)